# Backbone event context not keeping current state

Tags: backbone.js, require

I use backbone events to bind a context ( a view object ) to an event handler, that kinda work but the problem is that none of the propreties that were set in the initialize method seems to follow along with the context when the event is triggered. The code bellow illustrate the problem:

```
   define(['backbone'], function( Backbone ) {

        var PageView = Backbone.View.extend({

            /* Globals */
            pageExist: false,

            initialize: function( options ) {
                var self = this;
                self.pageExist = true;

                // _mediator is passed during instantition of the view
                // I've removed the code here as it's not relevant for this problem
                self._mediator.on("pin:add", self._pinAddCB, self);

                // Using bindAll seems a little bit better as the context now carries the aditional method that i added on this view ( like _pinAddCB ) 
                _.bindAll();

            },


            _pinAddCB: function( ) {
                console.log(this.pageExist ) // FALSE ??
            }
        });

        return PageView;
    });
```

Any ideas on how to go about this ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried how the code in your example works? Because it should work correctly.

1. `_.bindAll();` cause error in the newest version of underscore.
2. perhaps `pageExist` is modified by some other method.

Comment: 1 -I've tried with and without _.bindAll and it seems a little closer with it, without it the context is the view but the methods that i added to it do not seems to follow as when using bindAll they do
2- pageExist is only used in this module, beside i have other properties that are also set in the initialize method and same behaviour there.

Comment: Yea indeed, i just found the problem, very weird, the view is using an unsaved model and i was calling sync on it, somehow it messed up backbone in a very very odd way.. i just change it to save and now it works proprely.THanks for helping

Comment: Hoping to first figure out what went wrong, might have stumbled on a bug there, if not sure I'll accept it